# How do I check if a node.js process is being piped input from stdout?

Tags: node.js, bash, unix, pipe

I'm currently building a node app that accepts input from a python script. We plan on doing a pipe like this `pyton script.py | node index.js`.

I want to check that there is input being piped in. Such that if there is data being piped, start the express server. If however there is no data being piped exit the node process. I'm currently checking for input from the stream but I realized that I cant do this if there is no input from stdout. Does anyone know of a better solution?

Here's what I have so far.

```
import app from "./app";
import { PORT } from "./config";

process.stdin.setEncoding("utf8");

let key = "";
process.stdin.on("data", data => {
  key += data;
});

process.stdin.on("end", () => {
  global.key = key;
  if(global.key === ""){
    console.log("KEY UNDEFINED");
    process.exit(1);
  }
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Application started on port:${PORT}`);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go with the `get-stdin` module (https://github.com/sindresorhus/get-stdin). It has a better interface, based on `promises`. You can get the result from `stdin` and then start your express server.

```
getStdin().then(key => {
    if(key === ""){
        console.log("KEY UNDEFINED");
        process.exit(1);
    }
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`Application started on port:${PORT}`);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest one of the interesting npm packages you can use named "python-shell" and its features as following:

1. Reliably spawn Python scripts in a child process
2. Built-in text, JSON and binary modes
3. Custom parsers and formatters
4. Simple and efficient data transfers through stdin and stdout streams
5. Extended stack traces when an error is thrown.

and here is a simple example:

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

PythonShell.run('script.py', function (err,results) {
  //Results : array of messages collected during execution.
  if(err){
     //Error handling
  }
  else if(results.length > 0){
     //Start the server
  }
});
```